# C stack--last push overwrite previous ones

Tags: c, parsing, stack, push, overwrite

I read in C commands saved in `char*` (so basically a "string" of commands) byte by byte.

For example, "echo a; echo b".

Suppose I have `char *wd = (char *)malloc(20);`, and as I read a byte, store in `wd[i]`. If I see 'e', `wd[0]='e'`, `wd[1]='c'`, `wd[2]='h'`, `wd[3]='o'`, `wd[4]='\0'`.

And I have `char **wrd=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);` and I set `wrd[0]=wd;`. Then, repeat the loop which allocate space for `wd` again. Set `wd[0]='a'`, `wd[1]='\0'`, and `wrd[1]=wd;`

Then I combine `wrd[0]` and `wrd[1]` into `struct command`:

```
    struct command
    {
        union
        {
        char **word;
        } u;
    };
```

code to combine:

```
    wrd[wIndex]='\0';
    //initialize struct command called cmd
    cmd->u.word=NULL;
    cmd->u.word = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*20);
    for(m=0; m<wIndex; m++)
    {
        cmd->u.word[m]=strdup(wrd[m]);
    }
```

Then, I tried to push struct command to my stack implementation:

```
    struct Cstack
    {
    struct command *data[100];
    int size;
    }

    int Cstack_Push(Cstack *c, struct command *cmd)
    {
        if(c->size < STACK_MAX)
        {
            c->data[c->size]=cmd;
            c->size++;
        }
        else
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
```

However, when I do Cstack_Push multiple times, my last push overwrites all previous pushes. So when I tried to print u.word from each array of Cstack->data, it prints all same things.
Why is it overwriting them?

EDIT: Cstack_Push is called like this.

```
    struct command *cmd=(struct command*)malloc(sizeof(struct command)*20);
    cmd->u.word = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*20);
    for(m=0; m<20; m++)
    {
      cmd->u.word[m]=strdup(wrd[m]);
    }


    Cstack_Push(Cstack, cmd);
```

Comment: Please post a complete minimal code example, otherwise probably nobody can help you.

Comment: very confusing.  However, a 'union' is only a'union' if it contains more than one field.  The posted 'union' only contains 1 field.

Comment: when calling malloc(), and family of functions, 1) in C, do not cast the returned value.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: 'Cstack_Push(Cstack, cmd);' will fail to compile (when calling the sub function.  as the actual parameter need an instance of the Cstack, not the Cstack name.

Comment: the posted code has several instances of a 'magic' number (20).  this will be a maintenance nightmare.  use #define SOME_NAME (20)  then use SOME_NAME in all the places where '20' is currently being used.

Comment: struct command *cmd=(struct command*)malloc(sizeof(struct command)*20)  should be : struct command *cmd=(struct command*)malloc(sizeof(struct command))

Comment: this struct definition:  struct command
    {
        union
        {
        char **word;
        } u;
    };  only contains one field.  suggest removing the 'union' so the body is only 'char **word;